# How to layout UILabel which can have infinite number of lines

Tags: ios, swift

In ios, I can set UILabel number of lines to be 0 for dynamic number of lines depends of amount of text I set the label to.

My question is, if I want to layout 2 buttons right below the UILabel, how can I do that? since I don't know the height of the UILabel (depends on the text I set to, which can be varies), how can I position the buttons below the UILabel. And how can I adjust the ScrollView to make it scroll when necessary?

- ScrollView

  - UILabel
  - UIButton
  - UIButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use auto layout and set a constraint between the top of the buttons and the bottom of the UILabel.

The UIScrollView can be made scrollable programatically, perform a check by verifying whether the `contentSize` property is higher than the size of the frame, then set `myScrollView.scrollEnabled` true

Edit:

If you use .xib files, then you must select it, set `Use auto layout` enabled in the Show the File Inspector pane, the Interface Builder Document section (see photos).

[image]

[image]

Afterwards, in your interface builder, you select your button and place a top constraint between the button and the label (see photos).

[image]
[image]

Edit 2: note that you might have to add other constraints as well, so as to be able to correctly place your elements in your container.

Another way to do it is to use NSLayoutConstraints programatically. More details here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_auto_layouts.htm

Comment: Thanks. Where to set 'use auto layout'? in my ScrollView? I can't find that in the attribute inspector.

Comment: Thanks. I am using 'auto layout' in my project. I am using storyboard. I set the UILabel 'Lines' to 0. And In size Inspector I have the width, height set to 375 and 41. But now, only 2 lines of the text shows up. I guess it is bound by the 41 as height. My question is why UILabel does not grow the height? as i have set 'Lines ' to 0. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the height of the label with the below method

```
(CGFloat)findHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font  
{  
    CGFloat result = font.pointSize+4;
    CGFloat width = widthValue;
    if (text) {
        // CGSize textSize = { width, CGFLOAT_MAX };       //Width and height of text area
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 0)];
        label.font = font;
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        label.attributedText = text;
        [label sizeToFit];
        //        CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:textSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
        result = MAX(CGRectGetHeight(label.frame), result); //At least one row
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can call this method like this.

```
NSString *description = @"your text will go here";
    CGFloat descHeight = [NSString findHeightForAttributedText:description havingWidth:288 andFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-" size:16.0f]];
```

Now you have the height of the text.Set the frame of the text and you can also set the y of button by adding some margin to the above calculated height.

Comment: If I have created a UILabel, can I get a reference to that UILabel and call 'label.frame' after I set the attributedText to get the new height?

Comment: yes you can do that..https://github.com/sgup77/SGXmlParser .check this for reference. This is not exactly what you are looking for. but it will help you understand the above code.

Comment: I have a UILabel created in my View inside my Main storyboard. And I have binded that view to my swift class called MyCell.swift, which has  a " @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!"  My question is how can I do your findHeightForAttributedText() with my existing UILabel. Your function creates a new UILabel.